# What are methods for computing the descriptive statistics of interval measures?

Tags: repeated-measures, descriptive-statistics, interval-censoring

I do several measurements and obtain for each: $m_i = x_i \pm \delta x_i$.

What are the mean and the standard deviation of a such series of measurements?

Comment: What is it you want to know about these measurements? What are the original variables? What is the goal of your study?

Comment: I reformulate my problem, I think it is clearer now, Thanks for your help

Comment: The answer depends on what the "$\pm \delta x_i$" mean.  Could you elaborate on the measurement process and this meaning?  For instance, are you reporting estimated standard errors?  Or are you perhaps reporting "hard" intervals in which the measuring device tells you only that the $i^\text{th}$ value lies between $x_i-\delta x_i$ and $x_i+\delta x_i$?

Comment: Hi Whuber, 
I think your second assumption is correct. The device produces a series of measurements I need to process. In this processing there is an "unkown" parameter. I only know the bounds in which this parameter varies. So I do the calculation for the min and the max values. It gives me this interval: $x_i+\delta x_i$ and $x_i+\delta x_i$ (don't know how to qualify it precisely with the good semantic). Obviously $\delta x_i$ depends of the unknown parameter bounds and the measurements so it varies for each $i^th$ measurement.